# Are there market makers in bonds market?

Tags: bonds, market-order, treasury, market-making

When I order to mkt buy/sell stocks in US primary markets it excuted in seconds. In bonds markets, especialy in US treasuries, if I order to sell my bond or to buy an old bond, could my mkt order last for days, or it is like in stocks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bonds are not traded on an exchange like stocks, and so there are no "designated" market makers like for stocks, but there are some brokers that will buy and re-sell bonds to keep liquidity up (and to make a bit of profit for themselves).

So I wouldn't expect your bond trade to be executed in "seconds" but if there are buy and sell quotes listed I would expect an order within a few hours or so, but it completely depends on the supply/demand for that specific bond.

That said, be careful of the implicit transaction cost of the bid/ask spread. You always buy at the ask and sell at the bid, so if there is a significant difference ("spread") between the two, you'll need to hope that the bond price rises more then (or you keep it long enough for the coupons to overcome) the bid/ask spread.